# Проблемы с адаптером из библтотеки DragListView для Android

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в Android, пытаюсь использовать библиотек [DragListView](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) и не пойму как поставить адаптер? лазил внутри библиотеки, так ничего и не нашел... предложенный в коде адаптер на github `ItemAdapter` не существует, а тот который есть `DragItemAdapter` не подходит под `DragListView`

```
error: method setAdapter in class DragListView cannot be applied to given types;
required: DragItemAdapter,boolean
found: DragItemAdapter
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

не пойму, какие нужно передать аргументы, чтобы он заработал

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DragListView mDragListView;
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDragListView = (DragListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        mDragListView.setDragEnabled(true);
        mDragListView.setDragListListener(new DragListView.DragListListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemDragStarted(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemDragging(int itemPosition, float x, float y) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemDragEnded(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {

            }
        });

        mDragListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        DragItemAdapter adapter = new DragItemAdapter() {
            @Override
            public long getUniqueItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            }
        };

        mDragListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDragListView.setCanDragHorizontally(false);
    }
}
```

на всякий случай xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.woxthebox.draglistview.DragListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.woxthebox.draglistview.DragListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Прошу помощи, чтобы разобраться в применении библиотеки, т.к. хочу вживить в свою программу drag and drop

Comment: Ну так он вам ругается на сигнатуру `mDragListView.setAdapter(adapter);` а должно быть `mDragListView.setAdapter(adapter, true);`